# How to change jQuery slider value when it has been created by Zend Framework

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, slider

I have created a slider this way with ZF:

```
print("<div>" 
        . $this->slider("developmentEffort",
                      "",
                      array('min' => 1,
                            'max' => 10,
                            'value' => $this->value,
                            'animate' => 'slow'))
. "</div>");
```

And then I want to set new value to it when save link is clicked. But the following code does nothing.

```
$( "#developmentEffort-slider" ).slider( "option", "value", 9 );
```

nor does this

```
$( "#developmentEffort" ).slider( "option", "value", 9 );
```

I think this is because ZF creates hidden input field. At least it is different from the solution which is done without ZF and it works.

Html look like this:

```
<input id="developmentEffort" type="hidden" value="6" name="developmentEffort">
<div id="developmentEffort-slider" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
<div class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="left: 55.5556%;">  </div>
```

Also when I do this:

```
var value = $( "#developmentEffort" ).slider( "option", "value" );
alert(value);
```

I get an [object Object] notification, not the value.

So how can I get this work with ZF?

Answer (score 0):

If  the slider structure is as bellow with hidden values.

```
    <h6>Price:<span id="pr_out"></span></h6>
    <div class="aclass" style="padding-left:5px;">            
        <div id="pr_slider" style="width:200px"></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="min_price" id="min_pr" />
        <input type="hidden" name="max_price" id="max_pr" />
    </div>
```

You just use similar code to make it work

```
    $("#pr_slider" ).slider
    ({
       range: true,
       min: min_range,
       max: max_range,
       values: [init_min_range, init_max_range],
       slide: function( event, ui )
       {
             $( "#pr_out" ).html(ui.values[ 0 ] + " - "+ui.values[ 1 ] );
             $( "#min_price" ).val(ui.values[0]);
            $( "#max_price" ).val(ui.values[1]);           
       }
    });
```

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot make mine to work with this example. Still nothing happens. I added my html code above.